# Updating two tables inside a method in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, controller

Two forms will be displayed inside a page.
datas from secondary form will update the secondary table and datas from primary form will update the primary table.

The data from the secondary table should be displayed on the page after every addition and finally the main table has to be updated and the secondary table should be updated with status as "completed".

Can two tables updated in a single method inside the controller

Comment: [cake 2](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto)
[cake 3](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-with-associations)

Answer (score 0):

Use inside method adapted per your needs

```
$this->loadModel('YourFirstModel');
$this->loadModel('YourSecondModel');
$model1 = $this->Model1->get($model1_id); 
$model1 = $this->Model1->patchEntity($model1, $yourDataArray);
if($this->Model1->save($model1)){
   $model2 = $this->Model2->get($model2_id);
   $model2 = $this->Model2->patchEntity($model2, $yourDataArray);
   if($this->Model2->save($model2)){
       /* yay, I am great */
   }else{
      /* ask on stackoverflow */   
   }
}
```

If your data is associated, read this https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations

Comment: Thank you Mike.  I need to display the data from the secondary table in the same page before the primary table is updated. How to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can split your process between two diferent actions in the same controller, those actions can use the same view. For this, you may use the controller method
setAction(). It will pass all data from a action to another in the same controller.

e.g

```
public function saveSecondary(){
    //your stuff
    if($this->Secondary->save($secondary)){
        $this->setAction('saveMain');    
    }
}

public function saveMain(){
  //your stuff
  //you can continuing using $secondary and post data here, so use to add 
  //stuff to your view, when the time is come to save main data, you should 
  //use this action by posting the data directly to it (since all secondary 
  //data has alreary been saved)
  $this->render('savesecondary'); // use the same view
}
```